# Unity OpenCV 2.4.x plugin portability issue

Tags: opencv, dll, plugins, unity-game-engine

I have created a Unity Plugin for all the major platforms, but I am having an issue with the Windows version, which was built using `OpenCV 2411` on windows 10.  I pass an `cv:Mat Ptr()` to a `ID3D11Texture2D`, and it works splendidly when opencv is installed on the system.

I then began to remove any environment variables pointing to OpenCV, and dropped all of the dlls into the `Plugins/x86_64` folder as this is for the 64 bit Unity Editor.  I also renamed my OpenCV folder so that any pathing to it would be broken.  I wanted to see what someone that doesn't have OpenCV installed would experience.  When I hit play, everything was gray, but no Dll Exceptions!  So I then renamed my OpenCV installation folder back to it's original name, closed and opened unity, and then hit play and it worked. Once a dll is loaded in unity, you have to close and re-open it, to see changes.

It was time to start removing files and see which was still dependent.  I have narrowed it down to one file, `opencv_ffmpeg2411_64.dll`.  Every other file can be removed related to opencv and it will work using the dlls in the unity plugin folder.  `opencv_ffmpeg2411_64.dll` is in the same folder as the rest of the dlls, but it will only work if `opencv_ffmpeg2411_64.dll` is in `c:\opencv\2411\...`

Any ideas on why this one file has to be in the original installation directory and ignored in the `Plugins/x86_64` folder where the other opencv dlls are?

I have read every site related the the subject that I can find.  Some suggest static libraries, some have other solutions.  I see many opencv plugins using Dlls as opposed to static libs because of the order unity searches for the libraries in.

I am very close and would appreciate a nudge.  I have never really learned much about dll dependencies.